# Computing limit using definition of e

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

I want to show that for fixed $n\in \mathbb{N_0}$, there exists some $C>0$ such that $c>0$ implies $(1-\frac{1}{2^n})^{cn}\le \frac{1}{4c}$.

EDIT: Realize now from comments that the limit definition of $e$ probably won't be helpful here since $n$ is fixed.
[PROBABLY NOT USEFUL OLD COMMENTS: I'm thinking since $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{cn}=e^c$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1-\frac{1}{n})^n=e^{-1}$, we can take $n=\log_2 m$, but then I'm not really sure how to use the limit definition of $e$. ]

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: For c sufficiently large or n sufficiently large?

Comment: Is it even true?  I don't think so.

Comment: Are you asking "for any fixed $n$, does there exists a $c$ for which the inequality holds?"  Or are you asking "for any fixed $c$, does there exist an $n$ for which the inequality holds?"

Comment: The former: For fixed $n$, does there exist $C>0$ such that the inequality holds for $c>C$. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: Whoops, these comments have clarified for me that the limit definition of $e$ is probably irrelevant here, since $n$ is fixed. My bad.

Comment: Yes. Note that for any $n\ge1$, the left-hand side is a number less than $1$ raised to a positive power $cn$, which for incressing $c$ decays exponentially.  The right-hand side is simply decaying as $1/c$.  Show that $a^c\le 1/c$ for large enough $c$ and you're there.

Comment: Great, thanks a bunch!

Comment: Small $c$ works too.  For $n\ge 4$, take $c=\frac1n$ for obvious conclusion.